# check if wireless AP is connected

Tags: c, linux, encryption, posix, wifi

I am writing a linux wireless network scanner that provides information about access points, but it also must check if an access point is connected and can be communicated (i.e. encryption works properly). It is not enough to check it by `ioctl(.., SIOCGIWAP, ..)`, because it does not really check if the WPA key is correct and that AP can be communicated.

What I am doing to check if a wireless interface is associated with an AP is:

- check if `ioctl(...,SIOCGIWAP,...)` returns MAC address of some AP
- check if interface has IP configured (I know that it will give no information in case of static configuration, but I can live with that)
- check if encryption (e.g. WEP, WPA, WPA2) used by AP and client is the same (to ensure that after change of encryption method at the AP side, it will not be positively detected as connected).

I got stuck with the latest point - I can detect the encryption used by the AP, but I really do not know how to check what encryption is used by my host. Do you have idea how to check that? Or maybe you know better ways to determine if connection between AP and client is workning (I do not want to use ICMP or anything like this - my tool must be quick and thus do everything locally)

Answer (score 0):

Calling ioctl with SIOCGIWENCODE queries encryption key on or off (which distinguishes between Open and Encrypted).

Calling ioctl with SIOCGIWESSID queries the ESSID, you can then play ESSID matching between the host and AP.

Calling ioctl with SIOCGIWENCODEEXT queries the encryption type (which distinguishes between WEP, WPA and WPA2,etc) but only if it is supported by the wireless card's kernel driver.